# React Native websocket object not connected on first attempt

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket

I'm new in react-native and websocket.

```
 const client = new W3CWebSocket(
    'url/api/ws/chat/1/' + logID + '/',
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    getID();
    getPrevMsgs();
    client.onopen = (e) => {
      console.log('WebSocket Client Connected',);
    };
  
    client.onmessage = message => {
      const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(message.data);
      console.log('got reply! ', dataFromServer);
      if (dataFromServer) {
        setMessages(messages => [
          ...messages,
          {msg: dataFromServer.type, sender: dataFromServer.sender},
        ]);
      }
    };
    scrollHandler();
    return () => {
      getPrevMsgs();
      scrollHandler();
      client.close();
    };
```

Now as you see in the above code the issue is that when I come to my chat screen its not connected t WebSocket but when I press ctrl+s then it connects with the websocket, I also try to add this line *const client = newW3CWebSocket('url/api/ws/chat/1/' + logID + '/'); * in useEffect but the still the same thing happens. WHats the reason for that how I can solve this problem.

Problem: How to connect websocket automatically when I come to chatscreen?